# Will this spaceship collide with the star? (time dilation)

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, thought-experiment

I thought of the above thought experiment and arrive on 2 conflicting conclusions. I can't seem to identify the flaw in my reasoning.

Suppose there is a star 4 light years from earth that has will explode and turn into a white dwarf in 3 years (as measured in the earth frame). A spaceship travels to the star at 86% the speed of light.

According to earth's frame of reference, the journey to the star will take 4.5 years so the star will have turned into a white dwarf.

according to the ship's frame of reference, however, the journey will only take 2.25 years. Moreover, since the star is travelling relative to the ship in its own frame, the event of the star exploding will actually take 6 years. So the spaceship will collide with a white dwarf instead of a star.

I thought this had something to do with simultaneity, but I know that the events must be same in all frames of reference. **My collusions imply that collisions occur between different bodies depending on the frame of reference, which can't possibly be true, can it? Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: "the event of the star exploding will actually take six years"...six years from when?

Comment: from the start of the journey. In the ship's frame of reference, ofcourse

Comment: Then there is of course no reason for the time interval to be six years.   You have been asking a lot of questions that would answer themselves if you took a moment to draw the appropriate spacetime diagram.  It's a skill worth acquiring.

Comment: why is that interval not 6 years?  are you referring to the round off from 5.87? I shouldn't really need a spacetime diagram for such a simple calculation. Maybe im confusing something, mind pointing that out?

Comment: The interval is **negative**.  In the traveler's frame, the star explodes **before** the ship starts its journey (approximately 1/3 of a year before).

Comment: You need to put more effort into this question to make it answerable, otherwise, it puts too much burden on the answerer. I suggest defining an Earth coordinate $(t, x)$, and say: the star explodes at (2023, 4) (while it's still (2020,0) here). Then we have something to Lorentz transform into the ship's frame.

Comment: i am unfamiliar with coordinates like that. Could you please edit?

Comment: Where does 5.87 come from? I drew a Spacetime diagram (which really does clarify what is happening, even in the apparently simple cases) and pretty much agree with the conclusions of @WillO .

Comment: I used T’=gamma To

Comment: Helpful hints. As @WillO strongly suggests, draw a position-vs-time graph (a spacetime diagram). It is an underused way to organize what is going on, as well as give proper meanings to formulas [which are often misused]. Additionally, when possible, avoid velocities like (1/2)c or (sqrt(3)/2)c and instead choose velocities like (3/5)c and (4/5)c , which lead to triangles with pythagorean triples and thus easier arithmetic. Otherwise, there is an unnecessary numerical layer (like 5.87) that obscures the physics.

Answer (score 4):

1. In the earth frame, there is a star 4 light years from earth,
   due to turn into a white dwarf in 3 years.  A spaceship travels to the start at speed $v=\sqrt3/2\approx .866$.  (All speeds are stated as multiples of the speed of light.)
2. When the spaceship leaves earth, let's say the earth observer and the spaceship observer both set their clocks to zero.   Here are three events:

**A:** The spaceship leaves earth.

**B:** The star becomes a white dwarf.

**C:** The spaceship reaches the star.

3. In the earth frame, these have the following coordinates:

**A:**  $t=0$, $x=0$

**B:**  $t=3$, $x=4$

**C:**  $t=4/v\approx 4.62$, $x=4$

4. Lorentz transform to the ship frame:

**A:** $t'=0$, $x'=0$

**B:** $t'=6-4\sqrt3\approx -.928$, $x'=8-3\sqrt3\approx 2.804$

**C:**  $t'=4/\sqrt3\approx 2.309$, $x'=0$

As you can see, the order of events in the earth frame is first $A$, then $B$, then $C$ (the ship leaves earth, then the star explodes, then the ship reaches the star).  The order of events in the ship frame is first $B$ (occurring .928 years before $A$), then $A$, then $C$ (the star explodes, then the ship leaves earth, then the ship reaches the star).

So everyone agrees that the star explodes before the ship gets there.  We should have known this even before we calculated because $B$ and $C$ are spacelike separated.

This is essentially an elementary homework problem and I'm mildly ashamed of myself for answering it, but  I want you to see that if you took half the time you've been spending on these questions and spent it learning relativity, you'd easily be able to do this for yourself.

Comment: I am in high school and the special relativity taught here is only uptil the 2 equations for length contraction and time dilation(along with relativistic dynamics). Can this question not be answered using them only? Is learning lorentz transformation necessary for this question?

Comment: Moreover, the spaceship started out in a frame of reference where the star hadn’t exploded and ended up in a frame where it already had exploded. Since the transition can’t be instantaneous, does thus mean that an observer in the spacehip saw the lifetime of the star in “fast-forward” during acceleration?

Comment: 1)  Yes, you really need the Lorentz transformations.  Fortunately, they are easy:  $x'=(x-vt)/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ and $t'=(t-vx)/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.  You can check that these are the formulas I used to get from the earth coordinates to the ship coordinates.

Comment: 2)  Suppose you are facing north, and the north pole is 3000 miles straight ahead.  Then you turn ninety degrees, and suddenly the north pole is 3000 miles to the right.  You started off using a frame where the pole was in front of you and ended up with a frame where the pole was to your right.  Does that mean that you saw the pole travel thousands of miles during your turn-around?  I guess in some sense the answer is yes, but that's generally NOT a useful way to think of it.  It's simpler to say that you didn't see the pole move; you just changed the frame you use to describe it.

Comment: 2) continued.   What's happening with the spaceship and the star is *exactly* like what's happening with you and the pole.   The star explodes.  You *describe* that as happening in the future, just as you *describe* the pole as being in front of you.   You change frames.  (Changing your velocity in spacetime is *exactly* analogous to facing a new direction in space.)  Now you have a *new language for describing the times of events* just as when you turn around on earth, you have a new language for describing where the pole is.  If you want to call that the pole moving, that's up to you.

Comment: And --- this is key --- the new and old languages are *equally valid*.  That's true when you're talking about the location of the north pole and equally true in exactly the same way when you're talking about the time of the explosion.   You should think of the Lorentz transformation as a phrasebook for translating from one language to another.  The underlying events are unchanged, but depending on which way you're facing, you use one or the other language.  (Changing your velocity *is* changing the direction you're facing in spacetime.)

Comment: PS---If you can figure out a way to give me an email address without either blowing your anonymiity (assuming you want to avoid that) or violating the channel rules (I'm not sure what rules there are), I can send you some notes that I believe will clear up all of your onfusion.

Comment: that would actually be extremely helpful. My email address is hamzamkhan03@gmail.com. I don't really care about anonymity, but I will remove the email address later to avoid violating any rules

Answer (score 1):

It is a synchronization problem. When the two observers synchronize their clocks at earth (Let us assume the traveler accelerates almost instantaneously so it reaches full speed still at earth), the star that is current for the traveler is in the future for the person on earth. So for the traveler, the time left to explode is smaller than otherwise. Imagine the star becomes a red giant before exploding. This means that at synchronization time, it is possible that for the earth observer the star is still in normal stage, but for the traveler it will be already in red giant stage. When they synchronize their clock at earth, far away objects will still be out of synchrony. So the star will explode before the spaceship will collide, for both observers, of course. Both observers will agree on a single event in spacetime, such a the collision between two objects.

Comment: So in about 2.25 years, the ship observed an event that took 3 years in the earth's frame. This implies that time flowed faster for the ship's frame s compared to the proper frame and goes against my intuition of time dilation slowing down time. Moreover, does this mean that at ultra-relativistiic velocities, I could essentially see the entire universe unfold in a matter of years, days or even minutes?

Comment: time dilation does slow time, but there is also an initial lack of synchrony that overcomes it. It is easy to see in a minkowski diagram, do you understand them? you have a dilated time, but that time is already shorter, when the traveller  starts the trip, to him the star is already a red giant. His present is not the same than for people at earth

Comment: unfortunately, I do not. I have only an introductory knowledge of SR

Comment: Actually---the numbers in the OP don't quite make sense (the assumption about velocity is not exactly consistent with the assumption about length of journey, etc) but if they are even approximately correct, then in the traveler's frame, the star has already exploded **even before the traveler leaves earth**, not just before he gets to where the star used to be.

Comment: @WillO thanks, I hadn't check the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 when you can't figure out what's going on in a special relativity problem:  draw a spacetime diagram.  This is, by far, the best way to understand what's going on in most special relativity paradoxes.  If you want to actually understand what's going on with special relativity, rather than simply learning a few counterintuitive formulas, I highly recommend learning about spacetime diagrams.  [Here's a good set of lecture notes from Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eoas/SI/SRGR/notes/SRGRLect3_2015.pdf) about how to construct them and how to interpret them.  They're not hard (a high-school student such as yourself should be able to understand them), and they make everything so much clearer.

For your situation, we denote the events as follows:

- Event $A$: spaceship passes Earth.  (We'll assume, for simplicity, that it's zipping past Earth rather than accelerating from rest.)
- Event $B$: the star collapses into a white dwarf.
- Event $C$: the spaceship passes the location of the star/white dwarf.
- Event $D$: the "countdown" until the star's collapse begins.  In the Earth's frame, this countdown takes three years.

[image]

What we see, when we construct this diagram, is that the events you're concerned about happen in a different order in the spaceship frame.  In the Earth's frame, they happen as follows:

1. The spaceship passes the Earth (Event $A$).  Simultaneously, the countdown to the star's collapse begins (Event $D$).
2. The star collapses (Event $B$.)
3. The spaceship passes the location of the star, now a white dwarf (Event $C$.)

But in the spaceship's frame, the events happen in the following order:

1. The countdown to the collapse begins (Event $D$.)
2. The star collapses into a white dwarf (Event $B$.)
3. The spaceship passes the Earth (Event $A$.)
4. The spaceship passes the location of the star, now a white dwarf (Event $C$.)

In the ship's reference frame, the "countdown" to the collapse does in fact take much longer than the journey from the Earth to the star's location.  We can see this from the diagram — there's much more distance along the $t'$ axis between $D$ and $B$ than there is between $A$ and $C$.  But in the ship's reference frame, the countdown also starts (and ends!) well before the ship passes the Earth.  So there's no paradox with events happening "out of order".

Comment: When you refer to the "ship's frame" at the end, do you mean its final intertial frame or referring to the total time felt by the spaceship(including acceleration). What bugs me the most is that the ship started out in a frame where the star hadn't exploded and ends up in one where it already has. Since this process is gradual, not instantaneous, does that mean the an observer on the ship essentially saw the evolution of the start in a smaller time interval than an observer on earth?

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH: my answer assumes that the spaceship never accelerated — it was always moving at a fixed velocity, and passed the Earth at $x=t=0$. Talking about accelerated observers, and what they actually observe, is much trickier. In particular, defining which events are simultaneous according to an accelerating observer is much harder; see the “accelerated observers” section in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity). ...

Comment: ... But in that regime, neither the formulas you’ve learned nor the Lorentz transformations directly apply.

Comment: I see. All of these questions arise from  a hard sci-fi novel (tau zero) where a ship accelerates closer and closer to lightspeed and reaches the end of the unverse in a couple of decades. It essentially sees the universe grow old in fast forward, which is completely goes against my intuition of time dilation slowing down time for the observer.

Comment: Overwootch:  Regarding what your accelerated observer "sees", you have to be careful about what "see" means.  Do you really mean what the observer is actually *seeing*, or do you mean what the observer is *inferring* from what he sees?  In relativity, "seeing" is, perhaps confusingly, generally mean to mean the latter, but you seem (I think) to be using it to mean the former.  In that case, multiple observers at the same event --- some moving quickly relative to others, some accelerated, others not, whatever you want to assume --- all **see exactly the same thing**  (CONTINUED)

Comment: (CONTINUED) --- they see the photons that are arriving at that event.  All you can **ever** see is a photon that's hitting your eye, and if you and I are **at** the same place and time, then the photons that hit our eyes are all going to **come** from the same place and time.  So we will see exactly the same  thing, and again it doesn't matter who says who is moving, who is accelerated, etc.  Your frame has to do not with what you actually **see** but with how you **interpret** what you see.